# Spring Boot OAuth2 login not doing anything

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to get the user session managed with a OAuth2 provider and I made a custom login that made the calls, set the cookies etc... But then I realized that **Spring Boot Security has OAuth2 integration** and I decided to start from scratch and do it the right way.

The problem is that, for any secured path I access, I get redirected to the service, I log in in there, and then I get redirected back to my callback url, with the code as param and I get the template as usual, going through the controller, **not getting authorized on my application at any point**.

[image]

Before I used this code to access the API but as I understand now **Spring should be managing it**.

So, I autenticate, I get redirected again into my page (my callback url is permited for all users) and then I am at the same place, not authenticated in any way. I can't access any secured path.

What I did

application.yml:

```
security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          wca:
            client-id: 0YekXxbT20En0V000000Tk9pGam2K9HvIA0fTPP0
            client-secret: cm0001232132132132hGNICxzAwNKqFMg
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            redirect-uri: '{baseUrl}/loginWCA'
        provider:
           wca:
             authorization-uri: https://www.worldcubeassociation.org/oauth/authorize
             token-uri: https://www.worldcubeassociation.org/api/v0/me
```

SecurityConfig:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/loginWCA").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and().oauth2Login();
    }
```

Disclaimer: I know that I'm securing everything, my goal is to go to the root path -> get redirected to the provider -> log in -> get back to my web -> have a valid session to access root path as an authenticated user.

Answer (score 0):

You should get token after login passing. please ref your oauth2 provider.  then add it with Bearer in request HEADER 'Authentication'. So other pages need not be authenticated.

Comment: As I said, that was my first approach. I am asking how to make Spring manage it.

Comment: I think you should separate view page from restful api invoking. we always use oauth2 to protect api resource. in spring, to access a oauth2 resource, client need OAuth2RestTemplate. please ref sample of spring security in https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/tree/master/samples/oauth2: tonr responsible for view and sparklr provide api resource.